# How do I Close a Webpage using xPath?

Tags: xpath, google-chrome-extension

I'm using a Auto Clicker app from the Chrome Web Store and it does what I want it to however I dont understand how to Close my open tab after the task is finished. Here's the allowed expressions:

https://github.com/Dhruv-Techapps/auto-click/wiki/xPath

I've tried a bunch of different options with Ctrl+W but nothing seems to work. Am I doing something wrong or is it not implanted within the app itself properly? Is it even possible to tell the app to close the web page using Ctrl+W since no right click option exists for the very top of the web page?

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't a question about XPath, it's a question about a particular open source utility that allows you to test XPath expressions.

Comment: Correct. How do use the Application to close a web page?

Comment: I don't know. I only came here because I thought it was a question about XPath.